Blitz cache and user fields
We use user accounts with custom fields in the control panel to allow our staff create and edit a front-end staff profile. We have over 1000 users who do this regularly.
The issue I have with blitz cache is when a user updates their user account in the control panel,the save action doesn't refresh the page cache on the site front end like it does on a page update.
Is there a way I can configure blitz to refresh the user entry cache like a page entry
Thanks for any help

Blitz should track all cacheable pages as well as which user elements they track, and refresh cached pages as necessary. You can see which pages track which user elements using the Blitz Diagnostics utility.
If this is not working as expected, please create an official support issue, providing more details about your setup, and I’ll do my best to help you there.

Thanks for the insight , I got it sorted
